# pywin32 doesn't work on wine in docker container

Tags: python, docker, pywin32, wine

My application runs in docker containers. I run Docker desktop for Windows. So I've insalled a wine image for python3 https://github.com/webcomics/pywine/tree/main, updating the dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM tobix/wine:stable
MAINTAINER Tobias Gruetzmacher "tobias-docker@23.gs"

ENV WINEDEBUG -all
ENV WINEPREFIX /opt/wineprefix

COPY wine-init.sh SHA256SUMS.txt keys.gpg /tmp/helper/
COPY mkuserwineprefix entrypoint.sh /opt/
COPY wineapp wineapp/

# Prepare environment
RUN xvfb-run sh /tmp/helper/wine-init.sh

# renovate: datasource=github-tags depName=python/cpython versioning=pep440
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.5
# renovate: datasource=github-releases depName=upx/upx versioning=loose
ARG UPX_VERSION=4.0.2

RUN umask 0 && cd /tmp/helper && \
  curl -LOOO \
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-amd64.exe{,.asc} \
https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/download/v${UPX_VERSION}/upx-${UPX_VERSION}-win64.zip \
  && \
  gpgv --keyring ./keys.gpg python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-amd64.exe.asc python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-amd64.exe && \
  sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS.txt && \
  xvfb-run sh -c "\
wine python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-amd64.exe /quiet TargetDir=C:\\Python \
  Include_doc=0 InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1; \
wineserver -w" && \
  unzip upx*.zip && \
  mv -v upx*/upx.exe ${WINEPREFIX}/drive_c/windows/ && \
  cd .. && rm -Rf helper

RUN wine pip install pywin32

# Install some python software
RUN umask 0 && xvfb-run sh -c "\
  wine pip install --no-warn-script-location pyinstaller; \
  wineserver -w"

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Where I just added:

> COPY wineapp wineapp/

and

> RUN wine pip install pywin32

to the original dockerfile.
I've created the folder wineapp where I put an excel file called file.xlsx and a main.py. The main.py file is:

```
from win32com import client

print("hello")

# Open Microsoft Excel
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

# Read Excel File
sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open('file.xlsx')
work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[4]

# Convert into PDF File
work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,'MyPDF.pdf')
```

I've created a docker compose that build this container from that dockerfile.
After a "docker-compose build" and a "docker-compose up", the service starts. So, opening a shell and going inside the container, in the folder "wineapp" where the "main.py" file is located, I tried to execute:

> wine python main.py

and it execute the main file but with the following exception at "client.Dispatch" line:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'COM Error 0x800401f3', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\wineapp\pywine\wineapp\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in 
_GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'COM Error 0x800401f3', None, None)
```

So, it seems pywin32 library doesn't works. I think also that it is strange that some files are looked at directory "Z" and some at directory "C", I think it is this the error. By the way, pywin32 library is instaleld correctly, I checked run "wine pip install pywin32" and system says that it exists

Comment: @KJ The main problem is that I would like to generate a PDF file from the Excel and I don't find any good ways. One way is to use pywin32 but it works only for windows. Another way is to covnert excel in HTML and HTML to PDF using Pandas..but result is so bad: no formatting!